# Restfullyii limit and offset

Tags: search, yii, limit, offset, yii-extensions

Im trying to make use of `yii` and the `restfullyii` extension, I have managed to get the search working properly and now Im trying to `limit` the reults and include an `offset`, how would i make use of this module and its results, the search returns an array based on a `json` post, im using a rest controller as well

Comment: What is your question? Be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily set the limit and offset of a request using the _GET vars limit & offset. Here is an example URI:

```
/api/work?limit=10&offset=30
```